# using Threads with Jython/wlst

Tags: multithreading, wlst, jython-2.7

I'm working with weblogic servers and want a class to handle every connection separately with a handler in my scripts.
I'm using jython2.7 as interpreter and include all the weblogic libs need.

The Idea is to have a handler for every conncetion to the adminserver I have and controll them separately.
For this I wrote a class with the functions needed ( shutdown, getServers, etc ). The functions are working. My problem is the script only has the last connection established activ and not the connection in my class itself.

I thougt Processes would be the thing, and made something like this.

`p1 = Process( target = IDIHandler.connect, args = None )
p2 = Process( target = IDEHandler.connect, args = None )`

but it doesn't seem to work... The Process starts right away and not if I'm using p1.start() plus the same problem like above. only the last connected server is connceted.

I have to admit I'm not even sure if Process is the correct way for my Problem. If you have other options for me to try I'll do :)

Thanks in advance